Conjugate flows by a $C^1$ diffeomorphism implies similar Jacobian matrices.
I want to prove the following statement: Let $F : \mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ and $G : \mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be $C^1$ vector fields, and
let $p \in \mathcal{U}$ and $q \in \mathcal{V}$ be such that $F(p)=0= G(q)$. Suppose that there is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $h : \mathcal{U}\rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ with $h(p) = q$ conjugating the flows of $F$ and $G$. Show that the linear maps $DF(p)$ and $DG(q)$ are similar.
First, since $h$ is a conjugation, we have that for all points $t$ in the domain of the flow $f^t(x)$ associated to $F$, we have
$$h(f^t(x))=g^t(h(x)).$$
Since $h$ is $C^1$, we can differentiate the above equality, to obtain
$$Dh(f^t(x))Df^t(x)=Dg^t(h(x))Dh(x)$$
We cannot differentiate any further, so I tried using the following proposition: if the vector field $F$ is $C^1$, then the map $t\mapsto Df^t(x)$ is a solution to $X'=DF(f^t(x))X,\,X\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d,\,\,\mathbb{R}^d)$, by multiplying both sides by $DF(f^t(x))DG(g^t(h(x))$ to get an expression as mentioned in the proposition, and calculate it on the corresponding points $t=0$ and $x=p$, but I couldn't manage to get where I needed.
I'd appreciate any help or hint.

If we let $t=0$ in the second formula, we get $Dh(x)Df^0(x)=Dg^0(h(x))Dh(x)$, if we could differentiate it again, we would get easily what we're looking for, by using the above proposition I mentioned.

I think the following should work.
(I hope you don't mind if I write derivatives with primes instead of $D$. I find that easier to read.)
Applying $d/dt$ to your first equation and setting $t=0$ gives
$$
h'(x) F(x) = G(h(x))
.
$$
By shifting the origin of the coordinate systems we can assume that $p=0$ and $q=0$, so that $F(0)=0=G(0)$ and $h(0)=0$. Then, since $h'$ is continuous at $0$ and the vector fields $F$ and $G$ are differentiable at $0$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\bigl( h'(0) + o(1) \bigr) \bigl( F'(0)x + o(|x|) \bigr)
&
= G'(0) h(x) + o(|h(x)|)
\\ &
= G'(0) \bigl( h'(0) x + o(|x|) \bigr) + o \bigl( |h'(0) x + o(|x|)| \bigr)
\\ &
= G'(0) h'(0) x + o(|x|)
. 
\end{split}
$$
In this equality, let $x = s e_k$ where $e_k$ is the $k$th standard basis vector and $s$ is a real number, divide both sides by $s$, and let $s \to 0$. Then all the contributions from the “little oh” terms tend to zero, and what remains says that the $k$th column of the matrix $h'(0)F'(0)$ equals the $k$th column of the matrix $G'(0) h'(0)$. Hence $h'(0)F'(0)=G'(0)h'(0)$, since $k$ was arbitrary.
